I can't print user input as ascii characters in Odin
I just want to take user input and then print it back but it will just print numbers. I don't know how to convert a byte array to a string or an ascii character.
I just started trying Odin. There is a lot of information on the main site, variables, loops, strings etc. However I can't find anything about how to get user input and then print it. My attempt:
import "core:fmt"
import "core:os"
import "core:strings"

main :: proc() 
{
    
    fmt.print("Enter something: ");
    buf: [256]byte; 
    num_bytes, err := os.read(os.stdin, buf[:]);

    fmt.println("You entered:");
    fmt.print(buf);

}

This will just print all 256 numbers. I'm on Windows so I looked at the read function in the 'os' module:
read :: proc(fd: Handle, data: []byte) -> (total_read: int, err: Errno) {
...

So it takes in an array of bytes. All I need to do is print the byte array in char format.
The output when I type "hello":
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 13, 10, 0, ...

I don't want to see numbers, I want to see text.
How do I print a byte array as ascii characters?
Or how do I convert the byte array into a string and print that?


I want to see text.
How do I print a byte array as ascii characters?

    fmt.printf("%s", buf);


Thanks, I also found a way to convert the byte array to a string if anyone else needs it:
input := strings.trim_space(string(buf[:num_bytes]));
